# pandasql for pandas dataframe throwing error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, pandasql

My Pandas Dataframe named as data_five_minutes:

|  | script_id | date_time | open |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2019-01-11 09:35:00 | 25 |
| 1 | 1 | 2019-01-11 09:40:00 | 30 |
| 2 | 1 | 2019-01-11 09:45:00 | 48 |

Full ss:

[image]

Now I was trying to get only data which are having script_id as 1:

```
    data = ps.sqldf(f"""SELECT d4.script_id,d4.date_time,d4.open,d4.high,d4.low,d4.close,d4.volume
                          FROM data_five_minutes d4 WHERE d4.script_id = {id}""")
```

this is just small condition but in original it has nested where clause so SQL query will be passed on original code as earlier i was passing the same query in database.

I am getting below error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1752, in
> _e xecute_context
> cursor, statement, parameters, context   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 714,
> in do_executemany
> cursor.executemany(statement, parameters) sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "D:\python_projects\auto\testing.py", line 70, in 
> FROM data_five_minutes d4 WHERE d4.script_id = 1""")   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandasql\sqldf.py", line 156, in sqldf
> return PandaSQL(db_uri)(query, env)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandasql\sqldf.py", line 58, in **call**
> write_table(env[table_name], table_name, conn)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandasql\sqldf.py", line 121, in
> write_table
>
> ```
> index=not any(name is None for name in df.index.names))  # load index into d b if all levels are named   File
> ```
>
> "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 518, in to_sql
> method=method,   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1320, in to_sql
> table.insert(chunksize, method=method)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 756, in insert
> exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 670, in
> _execute_ins ert
> conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1263, in
> ex ecute
> return meth(self, multiparams, params, _EMPTY_EXECUTION_OPTS)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line
> 324, in _e xecute_on_connection
> self, multiparams, params, execution_options   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1462, in
> _e xecute_clauseelement
> cache_hit=cache_hit,   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1815, in
> *e xecute_context
> e, statement, parameters, cursor, context   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1996, in
> *h andle_dbapi_exception
> sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from*=e   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in
> rai se*
> raise exception   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1752, in
> _e xecute_context
> cursor, statement, parameters, context   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 714,
> in do_executemany
> cursor.executemany(statement, parameters) sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding
> parameter 2 - probably unsupported type. [SQL: INSERT INTO
> data_five_minutes (script_id, date_time, open, high, low, clos e,
> volume) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)] [parameters: ((1, '2021-05-25
> 10:30:00.000000', Decimal('1978.6'), Decimal('1985 '),
> Decimal('1978.1'), Decimal('1985'), Decimal('323')), (1, '2021-05-25
> 10:35:0
> 0.000000', Decimal('1985'), Decimal('1986.05'), Decimal('1982.75'), Decimal('198
> 3.85'), Decimal('954')), and so on...] (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)
>
> Process returned 1 (0x1)        execution time : 2.672 s Press any key
> to continue . . .